# Can't auto mount partition through fstab during boot

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fstab

help me understand.
I have this line in my /etc/fstab

```
UUID=13958fbc-ce35-4a2a-a144-9b1543270cf4      /DAS1TB ext4    defaults        0       0
```

this UUID corresponds to /dev/sdb1 that should be mounted on `/DAS1TB` folder.

The problem is that the partition can't be visible during boot, and even after; let me explain better:
after a normal boot through `lsblk` the output is just

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdb                         8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
```

As you can see, it does not display /dev/sdb1 as partition of device `sdb`.

Only if I launch, for example, `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`, I can see it through option `p` that allows to list partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000347463680 bytes, 3906928640 sectors
Disk model: TR-002 DISK00
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 3906926591 3906924544  1.8T Linux filesystem
```

After that, quitting fdisk, I have a new output for `lsblk`, that changes in

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdb                         8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdb1                      8:17   0   1.8T  0 part
```

And executing `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1` displays correctly

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="13958fbc-ce35-4a2a-a144-9b1543270cf4" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="dc101b80-f889-4c41-bb32-43fee1fd9ddd"
```

I tried also using `PARTUUID=` instead of `UUID=` in `/etc/fstab'

```
PARTUUID=6dd2947d-377e-4080-819f-a00f8c9d4462      /DAS1TB ext4    defaults        0       0
```

But again, the partition is initially not visible, if not forcing the check of the contents of the gpt table using, for example, `fdisk` command.

During boot, and after that, it is not discovered/located.

Further info: the device is a DAS (Direct Attached Storage) with 2-bays in RAID1 (so, it results just as 1 mechanical HDD disk of 2TB), connected through USB3.2gen2 interface.

Could you help, please? I need `/dev/sdb1` loaded during boot in `auto`.

Comment: I also tried the set of flags rw,suid,dev,exec,noauto,nouser,async instead of defaults: so, adding noauto instead of auto. Results, it boots normally without errors, but sudo mount -a does not return any changes to resolve the issue.